# Which variable of Counter-Strike 1.6 controlled the "Voice Transmit/Send Volume"?

Tags: counter-strike

I know that `voice_scale` controlls voice receive volume, but which one is for voice transmit volume?

Comment: Actually, voice_scale covers both input and output. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: i tried many times, when changed `voice_scale` value, the progress bar of "Transmit Volulme" does not steped/moved/changed, only the "Receive Volume" progress bar changed. I want to set these 2 values to config.cfg file, and make file read-only, so that I will not need to tweek them after next startup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I got the answer.

It's the Microphone Volume in Control Panel controlls the voice transmit volume.

But they are not synchonized. When adjusting one volume, the other one does not changed at the same time.

- When adjusting from Control Panel, you need re-open CS option dialog to see the new voice transmit volumne.
- When adjusting from CS, the new volume will synchronized to Control Panel only after click "OK" in the CS option dialog.